# How to kill/remove tray icons (KDE)

Tags: icons, system-tray

KDE, Ubuntu 20.04.

In this case, they are from some Wine/Proton (via Steam) app. I killed the app (the game itself ran fine, but it did not quit properly).
However, the icon still seem to be there. I think I already killed all wine processes I could find.

[image: fr]

(Here already 5 times.)

How can I remove the icon(s)? Clicking on it (or right click) does not give me anything.

Comment: If you're unsure you killed all of the running wine processes, you can use "system monitor. Once opened, type "exe", to get a list of all running "windows-executables" processes you then can kill (end process). That maybe it!

Comment: @v2r I did that, and the icon still there.

Comment: How did you close the game?! Maybe try another way to close it, like "xkill" or "cmd-key+q"? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the panel. Select Edit Panel. Move your mouse over the application you wish to remove and a menu will appear. Click remove.
All done.